# Covering four points by the vertices of a regular tetrahedron.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I’m looking for an explicit formula for the vertices of a regular tetrahedron that covers four given points.   In particular, I have these two questions:

1)  Given four distinct real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$,   is there a simple formula for four complex numbers $z_1, z_2,z_3, z_4$ such that the four points $(a_i,z_i)$,  $i=1,…,4$ in ${\Bbb R}\times{\Bbb C}$ form the vertices of a regular tetrahedron?    That is, 
$|a_i-a_j|^2+|z_i-z_j|^2$ is independent of choice of distinct $i,j$.

2) Same question but with $a_i$ complex.

As an example of the type of thing I’m looking for,  for three real numbers numbers $a,b,c$,  $(a,(b-c)/\sqrt 3), (b,(c-a)/\sqrt 3), (c,(a-b)/\sqrt 3)$ are vertices of an equilateral triangle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related (but different): ["Projection of tetrahedron to complex plane"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53756/409)

Answer (score 1):

For part (1):  Let
\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]
& v_2 &= \left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{matrix}\right]
& v_3 &= \left[\begin{matrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{matrix}\right]
& v_4 &= \left[\begin{matrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]
\end{align*}
These are the vertices of a regular tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centred at the origin.  Next, let
$$ u = \frac14\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1+a_2-a_3-a_4 \\
a_1-a_2+a_3-a_4 \\
a_1-a_2-a_3+a_4
\end{matrix}\right] $$
Note that $\langle u,v_i\rangle = a_i - \frac14(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)$.  Next, let $Q$ be any $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix such that $Qu=\|u\|e_1$.  Finally, let
$$ x_i = \|u\| Qv_i + \tfrac14(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4) e_1 $$
Then $\langle x_i,e_1\rangle = a_i$, and the $x_i$ are the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, as desired.