# Regular Tetrahedron rotation problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Say that I have a regular tetrahedron with vertices $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ sit on a plane. The height of $d$, above the plane, is trivial to obtain given the length of any edge.

If I were now to re-orient the tetrahedron such that vertex $a$ remains in contact with the plane but $b$ and $c$ are raised from it, how can I now obtain the height of $d$ above the plane, given the elevations of $b$ and $c$?

Presumably this is relatively trivial, but it is outside my area of expertise.

One thing to note is that I need to be able calculate the final algorithm fairly quickly in real time using the 'C' language on a fairly low power processor.

Comment: Do you know only the new heights of $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @amd I know the lengths of the edges and that $a$ intersects the plane (height = 0). Also I know the heights of $b$ and $c$. It's just $d$ that I need to derive for any valid combination of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: One can calculate the distance and write an explicit formula, so the language and the processor are more or less irrelevant. As long as they can compute square root accurately enough, you are good to go.  The formula is $$\text{dist}(d,\text{plane}) = \frac{\, \sqrt{6 \, s^2 + 8 \, \big(h_C h_B - h_C^2
- h_B^2\big)}}{3} \, + \, \, \frac{h_C + h_B}{3}$$
 where $h_B$ and $h_C$ are the elevations of $b$ and $c$ over the plane,  and $s$ is the edge-length of the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a synthetic derivation, using only elementary geometry. It contains the final formula for the distance.

Let $ABCD$ be the regular tetrahedron and let $\Pi_0$ be the
"horizontal" plane in question. Then vertex $A$ is on $\Pi_0$,
i.e. the plane $\Pi_0$ passes through the vertex $A$ and the rest
of the tetrahedron is on one side of the plane (above the plane,
in the upper-half space). Furthermore, let $B_0, \, C_0$ and $D_0$
be the orthogonal projections of the vertices $B, \, C$ and $D$ of
the tetrahedron $ABCD$ on the plane $\Pi_0$. In other words,
$BB_0, \, CC_0$ and $DD_0$ are orthogonal to the plane $\Pi_0$.
Let $$h_B = BB_0, \,\, h_C = CC_0 \,\, \text{ and } \,\, s = AB =
BC = CA = DA = DB =DC$$ Given $h_C, h_B$ and $s$,  our goal is to
calculate the length of the segment $DD_0$. For the rest of this
post, I am going to assume that $h_C > h_B$.

Let $G$ be the centroid of equilateral triangle $ABC$. Then $G$ is
the orthogonal projection of vertex $D$ onto the plane of triangle
$ABC$. Therefore, $DG$ is orthogonal to the plane $ABC$.

Let $G_0$ be the orthogonal projection of $G$ onto the plane
$\Pi_0$. Then $GG_0 \, || \, DD_0$ since both are orthogonal to
$\Pi_0$. Therefore the points $D, G, G_0, D_0$ lie on a common
plane and form a trapezoid $DGG_0D_0$ with edge $G_0D_0$
orthogonal to both parallel sides $DD_0$ and $GG_0$. Since $DD_0$
is orthogonal to plane $\Pi_0$ and $DG$ is orthogonal to plane
$ABC$, we conclude that the angle $\theta$ between the two planes
$\Pi_0$ and $ABC$ is equal to angle $\angle \, GDD_0$, i.e.
$\angle \, GDD_0 = \theta$.

Furthermore, let $E$ be the intersection point of line $BC$ with
plane $\Pi_0$. let $H \in AE$ be the such that $CH \, \perp \,
AE$, i.e. $CH$ is the altitude of triangle $AEC$ from vertex $C$.
Then, since $AE \subset \Pi_0$ and $CC_0 \, \perp \Pi_0$, it
follows that $CC_0 \, \perp \, AE$. Hence $AE$ is orthogonal to
the plane $CC_0H$ so $AE \, \perp \, C_0H$. Therefore the angle
$\theta$ between the planes $\Pi_0$ and $ABC$ is (by definition)
$\angle \, CHC_0$. Consequently, $$\angle \, CHC_0 = \theta =
\angle \, GDD_0$$

To solve this problem, we focus on trapezoid $DGG_0D_0$ and
calculate the edge-lengths $DG$ and $GG_0$. Then we calculate the
angle $\angle \, GDD_0$ and use all of this information to
calculate the edge-length $DD_0$ as  $$DD_0 = DG \, \cos(\theta) +
GG_0$$ This is possible, because $DG \, \cos(\theta)$ is the
length of the orthogonal projection of the segment $DG$ onto
$DD_0$ and the length of the orthogonal projection of $GG_0$ on
$DD_0$ is equal to the length of $GG_0$ because $GG_0 \, || \,
DD_0$ and $G_0D_0 \, \perp \, DD_0$. To calculate $\cos(\theta) =
\cos(\angle \, GDD_0)$ we calculate $\cos(\angle\, CHC_0)$ by
calculating the edges of right-angled triangle $CHC_0$. We already
know $CC_0 = h_C$. We find the length of the altitude $CH$ and
then by Pythagoras' theorem, we find $C_0H$. After that
$\cos(\theta) = \frac{C_0H}{CH}$.

**Step 1. Calculating $DG$.** Recall that $DG$ is orthogonal to
plane $ABC$, where triangle $ABC$ is equilateral and $G$ is its
centroid. Denote by $M$ the midpoint of edge $BC$. Then $AM$ is
the median, altitude and angle bisector through vertex $A$ of
equilateral triangle $ABC$, so $G \in AM$. Then triangle $DGA$ is
right angled and
$$AG = \frac{2}{3} \, AM = \frac{2}{3} \, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \, BC
= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \, BC = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \, s$$ so by
Pythagoras' theorem $$DG = \sqrt{DA^2 - AG^2} =
 \sqrt{s^2 - \frac{1}{3} \, s^2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \, s$$

**Step 2. Calculating $GG_0$.**  Let $M_0$ be the orthogonal
 projection of $M$ onto $\Pi_0$. Then $MM_0 \, \perp \, \Pi_0$ and
 since $CC_0 \, \perp \, \Pi_0$ and $BB_0 \, \perp \, \Pi_0$,
 while $M \in BC$, the segment $MM_0$ lies in the plane determined
 by the points $C, B, B_0, C_0$ and since $CBB_0C_0$ is a
 right-angled trapezoid with $M$ midpoint of $BC$,
$$MM_0 = \frac{CC_0 + BB_0}{2} = \frac{h_C + h_B}{2}$$
Furthermore, triangle $AMM_0$ is right-angled and $GG_0$ is
parallel to $MM_0$ (both orthogonal to $\Pi_0$) where $G \in AM$,
so by the intercept theorem
$$\frac{GG_0}{MM_0} = \frac{AG}{AM} = \frac{2}{3}$$ so
$$GG_0 = \frac{2}{3} \, MM_0 = \frac{2}{3} \,  \frac{h_C + h_B}{2}
=  \frac{h_C + h_B}{3} $$

**Step 3. Calculating $CH$.** As already mentioned, the segment
$CH$ is the altitude of triangle $AEC$, where $\angle \, ACE =
\angle \, ACB = 60^{\circ}$ so by calculating its area in two
different ways we get
$$CH \cdot AE = 2 \, \text{Area}(AEC) = CE \cdot CA \cdot
\sin(\angle \, ACE) = CE \cdot CA \cdot \sin(\angle \, ACB) = $$
$$ = CE \cdot CA \cdot \sin(60^{\circ}) = CE \cdot s \cdot
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = CE \, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \, s$$ Thus $$CH =
\frac{CE}{AE} \, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \, s$$ To complete the
calculation, we need to find the lengths of segments $CE$ and $AE$

**Step 3.1. Calculating $CE$.** Recall that $CC_0$ and $BB_0$ are
parallel because both are orthogonal to plane $\Pi_0$ and that by
construction $B \in AE$, because $E$ is the intersection point of
line $BC$ with plane $\Pi_0$. Then by the intercept theorem
$$\frac{CE}{CB} = \frac{CC_0}{CC_0-BB_0} = \frac{h_C}{h_C - h_B}
$$ which yields $$CE = CB \, \frac{h_C}{h_C - h_B} = \frac{s \, h_C}{h_C - h_B}
$$

**Step 3.2. Calculating $AE$.** Apply the law of cosines to
triangle $AEC$ with angle $\angle \, ACE = 60^{\circ}$
\begin{align}
AE &= \sqrt{CA^2 + CE^2 - 2 \, CA \cdot CE \, \cos(60^{\circ})} =
\sqrt{CA^2 + CE^2 - CA \cdot CE} \\
& = \sqrt{s^2 + \left(\, \frac{s \, h_C}{h_C-h_B}\,\right)^2 \,
- \, s \left(\, \frac{s \, h_C}{h_C - h_B}\,\right)}\\
& = \sqrt{s^2 + s^2 \left(\, \frac{h_C}{h_C - h_B}\,\right)^2 \,
- \, s^2 \left(\, \frac{h_C}{h_C - h_B}\,\right)}\\
& = s \, \sqrt{1 + \left(\, \frac{h_C}{h_C-h_B}\,\right)^2 \,
- \, \left(\, \frac{h_C}{h_C - h_B}\,\right)}\\
& = s \, \sqrt{1 + \frac{h_C^2}{(h_C-h_B)^2} \,
- \, \frac{h_C}{h_C - h_B}\,}\\
& = s \, \sqrt{\frac{(h_C - h_B)^2}{(h_C - h_B)^2} +
\frac{h_C^2}{(h_C-h_B)^2} \,
- \, \frac{h_C\, (h_C - h_B)}{(h_C - h_B)^2}\,}\\
& = s \, \sqrt{\frac{(h_C - h_B)^2 \, + \, h_C^2 \,
- \, {h_C\, (h_C - h_B)}}{(h_C - h_B)^2}}\\
& = \frac{s \, \sqrt{(h_C - h_B)^2 \, + \, h_C^2 \,
- \, h_C^2  - h_C h_B}}{h_C - h_B}\\
& = \frac{s \, \sqrt{h_C^2 - h_C h_B \, + \, h_B^2 \,}}{h_C - h_B}\\
\end{align}
Now, we are ready to finish the calculation for $CH$
\begin{align}
CH &= \frac{CE}{AE} \, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \, s = \frac{s \, h_C}{h_C - h_B} \, \cdot \,
\frac{h_C - h_B}{s \, \sqrt{h_C^2 - h_C h_B \, + \, h_B^2 \,}} \, \cdot \,
 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \, s \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3} \, s \, h_C}{2 \sqrt{h_C^2 - h_C h_B \, + \,
h_B^2 \,}}
\end{align}

**Step 4. Calculating $CH_0$ and $\cos(\theta)$.** By Pythagoras'
theorem for right-angled triangle $CHC_0$
$$CH_0 = \sqrt{CH^2 - CC_0^2}
= \sqrt{ \frac{{3} \, s^2 \, h_C^2}{4 \big(h_C^2 - h_C h_B \, + \,
h_B^2\big)} - h_C^2 \, }$$ $$CH_0 = h_C \, \frac{ \sqrt{3\, s^2 + 4 \,
\big(h_C h_B - h_C^2 - h_B^2\big) }}{2 \, \sqrt{h_C^2 - h_C h_B +
h_B^2}}$$ Since $\cos(\theta) = \frac{CH_0}{CH}$ we get
\begin{align}
\cos(\theta) &= \frac{CH_0}{CH} =  h_C \, \frac{ \sqrt{3 \, s^2 +
 4 \, \big(h_C h_B - h_C^2 - h_B^2\big) }}{2 \, \sqrt{h_C^2 - h_C h_B +
h_B^2}} \, \cdot \, \frac{2 \sqrt{h_C^2 - h_C h_B \, + \, h_B^2
\,}}{\sqrt{3}
\, s \, h_C}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3 \, s^2 +  4 \, \big(h_C h_B - h_C^2 - h_B^2\big)
}}{\sqrt{3} \, s}
\end{align}

**Step 5. The final calculation of $DD_0$.** Now, we are ready to
put all the pieces together and to derive the length of $DD_0$. By
what we have derived above,
\begin{align}
DD_0 &= DG \, \cos(\theta) + GG_0 = \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \, s
\right) \, \left(\frac{\sqrt{3 \, s^2 +  4 \, \big(h_C h_B - h_C^2
- h_B^2\big) }}{\sqrt{3} \, s} \right) \, + \, \frac{h_C + h_B}{3}
\end{align}
so finally
$$DD_0 = \frac{\, \sqrt{6 \, s^2 + 8 \, \big(h_C h_B - h_C^2
- h_B^2\big)}}{3} \, + \, \, \frac{h_C + h_B}{3}$$

Comment: I think that this is the direction I should be going in.  The only thing is that the height of points $b$ and $c$ may be equal, potentially giving a 'divide by zero' error. Do you have a work-around  for this scenario?

Comment: @KevinAcres When I derived the formula, I assumed that $h_C > h_B$. However, the final formula is more general than the derivation, because technically, I should add the special case $h_C = h_B$. However, the formula comes out the same. Even in the case when $h_C=0$ or $h_B = 0$. What matters is the final $DD_0$ formula, where there is no division by zero.

Comment: @KevinAcres The formula doesn't even care which one is greater $h_C$ or $h_B$.

Comment: This worked just fine when implemented. The stepwise derivation was also great to have.

Comment: @KevinAcres Great! I am glad it worked. I like when things work out :). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Choose coordinates with the origin at the center of the tetrahedron, and let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\in\mathbb R^3$ be the vertices. Note that $\sum_ia_i=0$. By symmetry
$$
  a_i\cdot a_j=\begin{cases}
    \lambda&\text{if }i=j,\\
    \mu&\text{if }i\neq j
  \end{cases}
$$
for some $\lambda,\mu$. Choose the scale so that $\lambda=1$ (this means the side lengths are $\sqrt{8/3}$). Then
$$
  0=a_1\cdot\sum_i a_i=\lambda+3\mu
$$
so $\mu=-1/3$. Also
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  a_j^T\left(\sum_i a_ia_i^T\right)a_k
    &=&\sum_i(a_i\cdot a_j)(a_i\cdot a_k)\\
    &=&\begin{cases}4/3&\text{if }j=k,\\-4/9&\text{if }j\neq k\end{cases}\\
    &=&4/3a_j^Ta_k
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Since the $a_i$ span $\mathbb R^3$, we have $\sum_i a_ia_i^T=4/3I$.

Now suppose the plane in question is $\{x\in\mathbb R^3\mid x\cdot n=k\}$ where $|n|=1$. The distance from $a_i$ to the plane is $d_i=a_i\cdot n-k$. Then
$$
  \sum_i(d_i+k)=\left(\sum_ia_i\right)\cdot n=0,
$$
$$
  \sum_i(d_i+k)^2=\sum_i n^Ta_ia_i^Tn=4/3|n|^2=4/3.
$$
Let $s_1=d_1+d_2+d_3$ and $s_2=d_1^2+d_2^2+d_3^2$. Then
$$
  s_1+d_4+4k=0,
$$
$$
  s_2+d_4^2+2k(s_1+d_4)+4k^2=4/3.
$$
Combining,
$$
  3d_4^2-2s_1d_4+4s_2-16/3-s_1^2=0
$$
Hence
$$
  d_4=\frac{s_1\pm\sqrt{16-12s_2+4s_1^2}}3.
$$
Note that for some values there are two positive solutions, since the tetrahedron can be reflected around the side spanned by $a_1,a_2,a_3$. If you assume the unknown vertex is the highest above the plane, then take the larger solution.

Comment: Your key eqn can be written $$4 (d_1^2+d_2^2+d_3^2+d_4^2)-(d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4)^2=2s^2$$ where $s$ is the tetrahedron's edge-length. (Note that, although derived for origin-centered figure, the eqn is translation-invariant. Thus, the $d_i$ can be taken as the (signed) distances to any plane perpendicular to the $z$-axis.) This is a counterpart to the result in the question ["Projection of tetrahedron to complex plane"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53756/409); like that result, this one works for many other polyhedra, w/some coefficient adjustments. (Writing $s$ in terms of circumradius helps.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only interested in the elevation, the situation you describe is what happens when you rotate the tetrahedron around some line $L$ by some angle $\theta$. Indeed, the plane supported by $a$, $b$ and $c$ intersect the horizontal plane exactly in line $L$ and meets it at angle $\theta$.
If you can figure out $L$ and $\theta$, then it is easy to find the new elevation of $d$.

Denote by $h(x)$ the elevation of point $x$ after the rotation and $\operatorname{dist}(x)$ the distance from $x$ to $L$. If $x$ was originally in the horizontal plane, you have $h(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x)\cos\theta$. If you apply this to $b$ and $c$, you can figure out the angle between the equilateral triangle $abc$ and line $L$, from which you can deduce both the distance from point $d$ to $L$, and the angle between $d$, line $L$, and the orthogonal projection of $d$ onto the horizontal plane... You can probably figure out the rest (but feel free to ask about it).

Comment: this may work better for me. I can probably split it up into 'pitch' and 'roll' calculations and do it in two steps, initially anyway.

Comment: @KevinAcres I just gave a quick look at the other answers. The other 2 are based on algebra and are more rigorous than mine. They also explicitly highlight that there are up to $2$ possible solutions. My answer is based on geometry, and will (kinda) fail if $\theta$ is greater than $\pi/2$ (or smaller than $-\pi/2$). It depends what assumption you make. Take your pick I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose an edge of the tetrahedron has length $1$, and let the heights of $b$ and $c$ after elevation be $j$ and $k$, respectively.

Place vertex $a$ at the origin of a system of coordinates. Let vertex $b$ be located in the $xz$-plane, so its coordinates, after elevation, are $(\sqrt{1-j^2},0,j)$. We can find the coordinates of $c$ by specifying that it is $1$ unit away from $a$ and from $b$, and $k$ units above the $xy$-plane.

$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

$(x-\sqrt{1-j^2})^2 + y^2 + (z-j)^2 = 1$

$z=k$

Solving these equations, we get the coordinates of $c$ as $\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-4jk(1-jk)}{4(1-j^2)}},\sqrt{\frac{3-4(j^2+k^2-jk)}{4(1-j^2)}},k\right)$. As a reality-check, note that when $j=k=0$, these expressions reduce to the appropriate numbers.

Finally, the vertex $d$ is at the intersection of the three spheres centered at $a$, $b$ and $c$, each with radius $1$.

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

$\left(x-\sqrt{1-j^2}\right)^2 + y^2 + (z-j)^2 = 1$

$\left(x-\sqrt{\frac{1-4jk(1-jk)}{4(1-j^2)}}\right)^2 + \left(y-\sqrt{\frac{3-4(j^2+k^2-jk)}{4(1-j^2)}}\right)^2 + (z-k)^2 = 1$

The height you're looking for is the $z$-coordinate of the intersection of those three spheres. The top equation can be solved for $y$: $y=\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2}$, and that can be substituted into the other two. Then the second equation can be solved for $x$, resulting in $x=\frac{1-2jz}{2\sqrt{1-j^2}}$. Finally, this can be plugged into the third equation, resulting in a horrific mess, which is nevertheless, after some simplifying, a quadratic equation in $z$.

Indeed:

$$\frac{2j\sqrt{A}\sqrt{1-j^2}+j-2k(1-j^2)}{1-j^2}z+A+\frac{\sqrt{A}}{\sqrt{1-j^2}}+k^2=2\sqrt{B}\sqrt{C(z)}$$,

where $A=\frac{1-4jk(1-jk)}{4(1-j^2)}$, $B=\frac{3-4(j^2+k^2-jk)}{4(1-j^2)}$, and $C(z)=1-z^2-\frac{1-4jz+4j^2z^2}{4(1-j^2)}$

If you square both sides of this, it's quadratic in $z$. Unfortunately, I have to stop here. If you have specific values for $j$ and $k$, you can plug them in, and then it won't be so bad.